# Inputing text into select2 list

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am working on an app that uses the [Select2](http://select2.github.io/select2/) plugin. I need to allow the user to type into the box to bring up options for them to select. I have that working. However, I also want to give the user the ability to enter new options into the list. I'm not sure how to do that. Currently, my Select2 initialization looks like the following:

```
$('#myField').select2({
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: 'Please select',
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  initSelection: function (element, callback) {
    var id = $(element).val();
    if (id) {
      callback({ ItemId: id, ItemText: selectedName });
    }
  },
  ajax: {
    url: '/api/suggestions',
    dataType: 'json',
    quietMillis: 150,
    data: function (term, page) {
      return {
        q: term,
        count: 3
      }
    },
    results: function (data, page) {
      return { results: data, id: 'ItemId', text: 'ItemText' };
    }
  },
  id: function (item) { return item.ItemId; },
  text: function (item) { return item.ItemText; },
  formatResult: function (i) { return i.ItemText },
  formatSelection: function (i) { return i.ItemText }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createSearchChoice` option is what you are looking for.

From the [documentation](http://select2.github.io/select2/):

> Creates a new selectable choice from user's search term. Allows creation of choices not available via the query function. Useful when the user can create choices on the fly, eg for the 'tagging' usecase.

In this function you can optionally check that the user is not typed in an existing element and then mark this new item with a `custom` flag in order to do the item creation on later in the changed event:

```
createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
    //optionally check that the item is not already in the list
    if ($(data).filter(function () {
        return this.ItemText.localeCompare(term) === 0;
    }).length === 0) {
        return {
            ItemId: term,
            ItemText: term,
            custom: true // mark the item
        };
    }
}
```

Then in the `"change"` event you can handle the saving of the new element when the `custom` flag is present

```
.on("change", function (evt) {
    if (evt.added) {
        console.log(evt.added)
        if (evt.added.custom) {
            //save to server, etc.
        }
    });
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3oaw1q5y/).

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're loading data via ajax option on Select2, and what would solve the issue is, if you would preload your data before Select2 initialisation eg :

```
var data = $.get('/api/suggestions');
```

And than initialize Select2 with the data variable you created previously.

Than do some implementation where users will add somehow data, and append them to the `data` variable :

```
data.push({ id : 'newID' , text : 'newText'});
```

Now you got new data, so just reload your Selet2 :

```
$('#myField').select2('data', data);
```

**EDIT :**

Without preloading data, you can do something like this :

```
var data = $("#myField").select2('data'); //Read all data from select2
data.push({id:5,text:"new item"}); //Add new item to data array
$("#myField").select2("data", data, true); //Update select2 data
```

Comment: I can't preload the data. Its some suggestions based on what the user has entered. Any other ideas?